# Misaligned Partition and Other Questions

Tags: partitioning

I've been casually using Ubuntu for a few years but this is the first time I've had real trouble installing the OS. I bought a Lenovo laptop and I've run into a few problems after installing:

1. After formatting the drive and installing Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit) the disk utility gives me the message "the partition is misaligned by 3072 bytes" and suggests repartitioning. I formatted and reinstalled and am getting the same message. How exactly do I align a partition properly?
2. The laptop in question has 4 gigs of RAM but Ubuntu seems to only detect 3.5. Why is this and what can I do to make sure the system uses all four gigs?
3. When shutting down the laptop hangs at the Ubuntu screen. The only way to turn it off is to hold down the power button.

Also, I've read that 64 bit Ubuntu has issues with flash. Is this still the case? Am I better off installing the 32 bit version of 11.10? Any help with these issues would be much appreciated as I'm in over my head here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This site works best if you ask one question per question. I suggest that you split this question up.

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not know about the partitions (1), but
2. I would guess it could be that your system has a graphics card/chip with shared video memory, like the graphic chips which are part of Intel iCore processors. If this is true, that missing memory is reserved for the graphics. This may be the case even if your system has also a dedicated graphics card with its own video ram. Also, some cards may have its own video ram, but it can be expanded by shared RAM. It should be possible to set the amount of RAM dedicated for the graphics in the BIOS, and maybe also in some manufacturer tools within original Windows, if it came with that OS. In the case of system with dedicated video card along with a built-in one with shared video RAM, it should be possible to disable the later (again in BIOS) if it is not used.
3. Such problems can be solved by boot parameters, try to look for example at this:

http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/08/04/howto-fix-linux-hangfreeze-during-reboots-and-restarts/

http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions